# List<T> moving to the next element

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I searched SO and found some posts, but could not get them to work.

Question: How would I loop to the next item in my List Collection (custLoginHist[1] etc)?

```
    List<eCommCustomer.oCustomer> custLoginHist = new List<eComm.oCustomer>();
    eCommCustomerDAL.GetCustomerPrevLogin(custLoginHist, oCust);

    if (custLoginHist.Count > 0)
    {
        eCommSecurityFactory oSecFactory = new eCommSecurityFactory();
        if (oCust.CustHash == oSecFactory.CreateHash(custLoginHist[0].CustSalt, custLoginHist[0].CustHash))
        {
            //Password has been used before;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Valid password;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you just trying to iterate over the collection?

Comment: @DavidB move to the next item in custLoginHist

Comment: As others have pointed out, since it's a List it implements IEnumerable, you can just use a foreach over it. No need to use indexers or for loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach(eCommCustomer.oCustomer cust in custLoginHist)
{
  //Do something with cust here.
}
```

OR:

```
for(int i = 0; i != custLoginHist.Count; ++i)
{
  eCommCustomer.oCustomer cust = custLoginHist[i];
  //Do something with cust here.
}
```

In this case, we want to return false for any single match, and true otherwise, so:

```
foreach(eCommCustomer.oCustomer cust in custLoginHist)
  if(oCust.CustHash == oSecFactory.CreateHash(custLoginHist[0].CustSalt, custLoginHist[0].CustHash)
    return false;
return true;//if we reached here, no matches.
```

This is a bad idea though, because you've made breaking into the system easier. If I try to set my password to something, and you refuse, I now know that one of your users uses that password. You are much better off letting this case happen, though you should perhaps be blocking some of the more likely offenders ("password", "password1", etc) with a quality check.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<eCommCustomer.oCustomer> custLoginHist = new List<eComm.oCustomer>();
eCommCustomerDAL.GetCustomerPrevLogin(custLoginHist, oCust);

foreach (var custLogin in custLoginHist)
{
    eCommSecurityFactory oSecFactory = new eCommSecurityFactory();
    if (oCust.CustHash == oSecFactory.CreateHash(custLogin.CustSalt, custLogin.CustHash))
    {
        //Password has been used before;
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Try something like this, maybe you have to customize your return statements but it should give you an insight how it works.

Comment: This will not actually loop through the entire list. It will return from the function after one iteration, so will only inspect the first element.

Comment: That's right, I edited my answer a bit but it's also not 100% what the op wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(var item in yourList)
{
   //Iterate;
}
```

If you want break , you can use :  break;

If you want finish you can use : continue;

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can just use `foreach` or if you to be able to edit `T` in the loop, you can use `for`.

```
foreach(var item in custLoginHist)
{

}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < custLoginHist.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Then if you need to exit out of the loop before it is completed (such as if you have a condition that is true, you can just use `break;` to exit the loop, or you can `return` from a loop too if you want to return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can you loop for this. For example `foreach` or `for`:

```
foreach (var custLogin in custLoginHist)
{
    eCommSecurityFactory oSecFactory = new eCommSecurityFactory();
    if (oCust.CustHash == oSecFactory.CreateHash(custLogin.CustSalt, custLogin.CustHash))
    {
        //Password has been used before;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Valid password;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<eCommCustomer.oCustomer> custLoginHist = new List<eComm.oCustomer>();
eCommCustomerDAL.GetCustomerPrevLogin(custLoginHist, oCust);



return custLoginHist.Select(c=>oSecFactory.CreateHash(c.CustSalt,c.CustHash))
                    .Any(x=>x==oCust.CustHash)
```